# phonegap compass: Everything working but navigator.compass

Tags: cordova, compass-geolocation

In my project is working everything but the compass function.

I tried and build successfully a compass example project. But in my project my compass code doesn't work and the compass example project when compiled along with my project (as another page) doesn't work either.

The console.log(navigator.compass) message is undefined... Like if there is no compass or compass is not defined for navigator, why could it be that?

I've been dealing with this for days, and I have no idea why is that happening. Config.xml should be ok, but there must be something in my project that blocks the compass?¿ Is that posible?

Here is the config.xml:

```html
<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.bla.bla"
        version   = "1.0.0"
        versionCode = "10">

    <name>blabla</name>

    <description>
    blbla

    <author href="www.webpage.es" email="imail@gmail.com">
       Props
    </author>
    
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <gap:platform name="winphone"/>
    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
 <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
 
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />

    <!-- Plugins -->

    <!-- Core plugins -->


    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" version="0.3.9" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
   <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
      
      <!--
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts"
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />

-->


    <!-- Third party plugins -->
    <!-- A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/plugins -->
    <!--
        <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="icon/android/android_36.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
    <icon src="icon/android/android_48.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
    <icon src="icon/android/android_72.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
    <icon src="icon/android/android_96.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="icon/bb/bb_80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <icon src="icon/bb/bb_80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
    <icon src="icon/ios/ios_57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon/ios/ios_72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="icon/ios/ios_114.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icon/ios/ios_144.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="icon/webos/icon_64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
    <icon src="icon/windows-phone/icon_48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="icon/windows-phone/icon_173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
 <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/android/screen_ldpi_portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/android/screen_mdpi_portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/android/screen_hdpi_portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/android/screen_xhdpi_portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
 
    <gap:splash src="screen/bb/bb2_00.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
 
    <gap:splash src="screen/ios/screen_iphone_portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/ios/screen_iphone_portrait_2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/ios/screen_iphone_portrait_3x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/ios/screen_ipad_portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/ios/screen_ipad_landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
 
    <gap:splash src="screen/windows-phone/screen_portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />




</widget>
```

And here I have my javascript (that should work, and everything does but the navigator.compass, which returns undefined:

```js
$(function() {
 
  var currLat; //Current latitude
  var currLon; //Current longitude
  var targetlat; //Target latitude
  var targetlon; //Target longitude
  var dist; //distance to the monument
        var currentPos; //current position
        var targetPos; //target position
 
        var currHeading; //current heading
        var targetBearing; //target bearing
   
       inicio();
       
       function inicio()
       {
        watchPos();
        watchCompass();
       }

        function watchPos() {
        
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(posSuccess, posError, 
    {enableHighAccuracy: true,
     timeout: 1000,
     maxiumumAge: 0});
             }  
  }
      
        function posSuccess(position) {
   targetlat = $('#latMonumento').data('lat');
   targetlon = $('#lonMonumento').data('lon');
            currLat = position.coords.latitude;
            currLon = position.coords.longitude;
   dist = calculateDist(currLat, currLon, targetlat, targetlon);
            pushHtmlData();
            currentPos = new LatLon(currLat, currLon); //Using LatLon.js
         updatePos(targetlat, targetlon);
  }
  
        function posError(err) {
   currLat = 36.7467849;
   currLon = -5.167447999999999;
   targetlat = $('#latMonumento').data('lat');
   targetlon = $('#lonMonumento').data('lon');
   dist = calculateDist(currLat, currLon, targetlat, targetlon);
   alert("Error "+err)
            pushHtmlData2();
  }
      

        function watchCompass() {//Check compass 
            if(navigator.compass) {//Busca el compass, y si lo detecta lanza las correspondientes funciones
    navigator.compass.watchHeading(successCompass, failCompass, {frequency: 1000});} 
   alert("this is the compass " + navigator.compass)
   }
  
  function successCompass(heading) {
     alert("Compass ok. Heading: " + heading);
            currheading = heading.trueHeading >= 0 ? Math.round(heading.trueHeading) : Math.round(heading.magneticHeading);
            updateDiff();
  }
  
  function failCompass(error) {
   alert("Compass fail. Error: " + error);
  }


        function updatePos(lat,lon) {
         alert("targetPos");
            targetPos = new LatLon(lat, lon); 
            targetBearing = Math.round(currentPos.bearingTo(targetPos));
            updateDiff();
        }
    
      
        function updateDiff() {
            var diff = targetBearing - currHeading; 
            $('#Test').text("Grados hacia el monumento: "+diff+" grados.");
            $arrow.css("-webkit-transform", "rotate("+diff+"deg)");    
        }
      
  
  function calculateDist(latAct, lonAct, latDest, lonDest) {//Calculate distance to the monument
     var R = 6371; // km
     var dLat = (latDest - latAct).toRad();
     var dLon = (lonDest - lonAct).toRad(); 
     var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
       Math.cos(latAct.toRad()) * Math.cos(latDest.toRad()) * 
       Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2); 
     var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)); 
     var d = R * c;
     d *= 1000;
     d = Math.round(d);
     return d;
    }
      
        function pushHtmlData2() {
   $('#Dist').text("Distancia del monumento al centro de Ronda: "+dist+" metros.");
   $('#Advice').text("Activa los servicios de ubicación para conocer tu distancia al monumento.");
  }

        function pushHtmlData(){
   $('#Dist').text("Distancia: "+dist+" metros.");
  }
  
  

  //Helpers:
  Number.prototype.toDeg = function() { //Radians to degrees
          return this * 180 / Math.PI;
     };
  
  Number.prototype.toRad = function() {//Convert to radians
    return this * Math.PI / 180;
  };


});
```

Comment: do the relevant permissions exist in AndroidManifest.xml? I think you need android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: I'm building it with phonegap build which automatically generate it just with the config.xml... anyway, I've solve the problem forgetting about the compass function, aand doing it myself what I needed using event.alpha functions and some calculations. Thanks anyway